# Some doubts about how Prolog automatically convert DCG grammars int a set of rules

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am studying DCG grammar in Prolog using Ivan Bratko book: "Programming for Artificial Intelligence" and I am finding some problem to understand how Prolog automatically convert a DCG grammar into a set of Prolog rules.

For example I have the following DCG grammar:

```
move --> step.
move --> step, move.

step --> [up].
step --> [down].
```

Where:

**moove** is a list of possibile mooves and **step** is a single move that could be **up** or **down**

So it say that a list of moves coul be a single move (a step) or a list a list composed by more moves that can be see as a single move (a step) followed by a list of moves (a move).

So this grammar can generate phrase like the following list: [up, down, down, up, down] or like: [up]

This is pretty simple

Then he show how Prolog automatically converts the previous DCG grammar into a set of standard Prolog rules (I have renamed it as move2 and step2 only because I have put this code in the same file of the previous DCG grammar):

```
/* move2 it is TRUE if the difference from the lists List and Rest is an
   acceptable move.
*/

/* BASE CASE: A moves list can be a single move (a step that can be "up" or "down")
   It is TRUE that the difference from the lists List and Rest is an acceptable move
   if it is TRUE that the head of the list is an acceptable move
*/
move2(List, Rest) :- step2(List, Rest).

/* GENERAL CASE: A moves list can be a single move followed by a list of moves.
   The difference of List1 and Rest is a valid move if it is TRUE that:
   the difference between List1 and List 2 is a step
   the difference between List2 and Rest is a move
*/ 
move2(List1, Rest) :- step2(List1, List2),
                      move2(List2, Rest).

/* step predicate extract a single step ("up" or "down") from a list
*/
step2([up|Rest], Rest).

step2([down|Rest], Rest).
```

I tried to interpret the meaning of these rule as I have write in the comment but I am not so sure about my interpretaion...

Can you give me some hints to well understand it?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code or your interpretation, though I think you're looking at it "declaratively" without looking at it as a DCG. I would probably write this code like this instead:

```
step --> [up].
step --> [down].

move --> [].
move --> step, move.
```

This should work equivalently, but it will be a lot easier to extend and maintain than yours, because it doesn't explicitly maintain the difference list.

The closer you can get your Prolog to a natural-language expression of your intent, the better. If it takes a lot of words to explain how your code works, you're programming procedurally. The above Prolog is about as close as we can get out-of-the-box. We could go further by creating some helpers:

```
one_or_more(_, [])    --> [].
one_or_more(R, [V|Vs]) --> 
  { Rule =.. [R, V] }, 
  Rule, 
  one_or_more(R, Vs).

step(up)   --> [up].
step(down) --> [down].

moves(Steps) --> one_or_more(step, Steps).
```

(The above code is **untested**.) The point is to illustrate the power of declarative programming. It might be more work to write a predicate like `one_or_more//2`, but once you have it, the rest of your program is elevated to a more declarative style. Some comments might be necessary around `one_or_more//2`, because it isn't immediately obvious *how* it works (*if* it even works). The declarative reading of the above is, "move(Steps) matches one or more steps." This is the same as the declarative reading of my original version, and the declarative reading of yours. The difference is that the code for each is closer to the obvious declarative reading.

Comment: Your `move//0` is not equivalent to what OP posted, since it also accepts the empty list, but OP's definition does not. Also `one_or_more//2` should be called `zero_or_more//2` to reflect this.

Comment: mmm I have some doubt regarding this line of code: Rule =.. [R, V]

What is =.. ?